# Logs Files will reduce the website speed in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Sorry for this basic question
  I logging($this->log()) lot of things from all controllers in my live site. My tmp/logs folder contain around 1 gb of log files, whether this will reduce the site speed/ or slows site speed? we are removing log files once in a week from live server

Comment: Well, does it? It's your server. Does the speed improve when you've removed the log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes it will affect performance

If you have large log files, before writing to the log it's necessary to scan to the end of the log file - although this is not normally noticable it can with large files degrade performance.

It's for this reasons that tools like [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) exist; and why it's a good idea to get in the habit of deleting/archiving your log files from time to time - or regularly if they are building up quickly.

Answer (score 0):

the impact of writing log is pretty negligible (although I don't know how much you are logging). Besides, try to limit logging to debugging purpose, when you are done, remove it.